# Proceeding integral or summation calculation with no explicitly designated quantities, but instead with an abstract 'n' quantities

Tags: numerical-value

Could someone kindly tell me how to calculate formulas such as integral or summation with no explicitly designated algebra quantities as derivatives or summands, but the abstract ' n' quantities instead.
The thing is  I'm calculating a formula with the format below (I made some simplifications), known :

$$
    \Delta(x,y):=\left[\sqrt{x_{i}^{2}+y_{j}^{2}}\right]_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}
  $$
I want to calculate the gradient w.r.t the vector of all $x_{i}$.

$$
\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\left(-log\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{-\Delta(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})}}\right)
  $$

Usually in Mathematica, implementing traversing can be accomplished by **'Table'** directive, but unfortunately, it needs to designate algebra explicitly, **Table[*expr*,{i,I*max*}]** ,here since ***n*** is an abstract number, it is inapplicable to the calculation here.

So here is my question, is there any method that is capable to proceed calculation under the generalization situation that the parameters participating in the computation are not a necessity of exact quantity but an abstract number such as $x_{n}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify it further, and also give your concrete example, without sinplification?

Comment: Sorry, I was updating my question, now it has been completed. I just want to proceed with the calculation with abstract number parameters such as from x1 through xn, not explicitly from, for instance, 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 sum = Inactivate[Sum][
  Exp[-Sqrt[x[i]^2 + y[j]^2]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, m}]
grad = Grad[-Log[sum], {x[i], y[j]}]
```

Recognizing that Grad[r] = n = {x,y}/r you can write this in terms of n

Comment: Thanks, it works. I noticed for the number span from 1 to xn (not simply like 1 to 10 for example, the exact length of that is unknown), you used Grad[expr, {xi}] to get all partial derivatives of unknown lengths from 1 to xn, but my question is will it still work for other directives by utilizing the same Directive[expr,{xi}] method?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking. Do you mean Derivative instead of Directive?  You can certainly use {Derivative[1,0][f[x,y]],Derivative[0,1][f[x,y]]} to compute a gradient.  I think the Details section in Derivative has an example.

Comment: My meaning is if I have a function with parameters from x1 to xn (n is unknown), I want to proceed with Derivative or Grad or other mathematical deduction against x1 to xn (n is unknown). Usually if n was explicitly designated to be 15 (for example), things would be easy then.  So if for an abstract number n,  is there any general method yet to proceed with mathematical deduction?